# How to get/edit text output from Voice Typing IME

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice, ime

I'm beginner in voice recognization in android
I'm following this [tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/12/add-voice-typing-to-your-ime.html) to create a Voice Typing IME

I spent all day to find the way to access and modify text output from voice recognized of IME.
I tried to edit any attributes may return text recognized from classes:

- ActivityHelper 
- ImeTrigger
- IntentApiTrigger
- ServiceBridge
- ServiceHelper
- Trigger
- VoiceRecognitionTrigger

But it doesn't work :(
Anyone have a suggestion? Thank a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial has a jar that you can import to your code - alternatively you can import the classes separately. [They are available here](https://code.google.com/p/google-voice-typing-integration/source/browse/VoiceImeUtils/src/com/google/android/?r=08e8eb116b8bedafb6036a6f1aeb3be996935559#android/voiceime).

Looking at the class [IntentApiTrigger](https://code.google.com/p/google-voice-typing-integration/source/browse/VoiceImeUtils/src/com/google/android/voiceime/IntentApiTrigger.java?r=08e8eb116b8bedafb6036a6f1aeb3be996935559) it appears to have many references to the text that will populate the EditText field.

```
private void postResult(String recognitionResult) {
    mLastRecognitionResult = recognitionResult;

    // Request the system to display the IME.
    getInputMethodManager().showSoftInputFromInputMethod(mToken,
            InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

There are other references in the methods:

```
private void commitResult() {
```

And

```
private String format(ExtractedText et, String result) {
```

You should be able to manipulate them from there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it's curious why this voiceimeutils.jar, VoiceRecognitionTrigger has very very long timeout?